# SQlite in NetBeans

Tags: sqlite, netbeans

hi I am trying to add sqlite driver into my netbeans 6.9.1 project, these are the steps that I have done :

1. adding the the sqlitejdbc-v056.jar into the the libraries of my project
2. in "services" tab in netbeans, creating a driver with a name of "SQLite" ,adding the driverfile and finding the driver class (org.sqlite.JDBC) for the Driver.
3. now by right clicking on the driver and selecting "Connect Using", I have to add a JDBC URL connection for this driver, but any kind of URL that I add I keep getting this message :

> Unable to add connection. cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlite:/ using org.sqlite.JDBC -unable to find a suitable driver-.

please let me know how to create this connection for a simple database.
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are working on windows, change all backslashes to slashes in your path. This one I'm using right now:

```
jdbc:sqlite://T:/data/sampledb.sqlite
```